# "the movie" vs "an amazing movie"

Tags: word-usage, definite-article, indefinite-article

> Did you see **the** movie about Dian Fossey's work with mountain gorillas?   It was **an** amazing film.

Why is the indefinite article, ***an***, used in the second sentence?

It's the same film they are talking about. Is it because the descriptive adjective in front of the noun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Did you see the movie about Dian Fossey's work with mountain gorillas? It was **an** amazing film.

No, DaBu. Without the descriptive adjective (*amazing*) we would also place the indefinite article there:

> Did you see the movie about Dian Fossey's work with mountain gorillas? It was **a** film.

It's because in the second sentence we are using the pronoun **it** to refer to that particular movie, and then we give a description to **it** (**the** movie): it belongs to a group of films we would call amazing. There could be hundreds of amazing films, and **it** is part of that multitude.

Since there are many amazing films in existence, we use the indefinite article.

We could rephrase the sentences thus, putting "the film" instead of "it":

> Did you see the movie about Dian Fossey's work with mountain gorillas? **The** film was **an** amazing film.

See?

But we can make the second sentence use **the** with *amazing film* if we make "the amazing film" the unique referent to "the movie":

> Did you see the movie about Dian Fossey's work with mountain gorillas? **The** amazing film is **a** 3-hour long cinematic feast.