# "This is true, whether John has heard about ..."

Tags: sentence-construction

A [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/97534/109190) says

> In short, the reason sounds better, because in life as we and John know it, there is usually only one reason given by, or on behalf of, a murderer. **This is true**, whether John has heard about this specific case, this specific trial, this specific murderer, or not.

"This is true, whether", what grammar pattern is it?

I understand this simple conversation

> A: Is this true? Did you really win that competition?
>
> B: This is true.

I also understand another case

> ... this is true, no matter John has heard about ...

I don't understand the structure and the meaning of the whole sentence "This is true, whether John has heard about ..."

I understand the basic form of subordinate clauses, the part starting with whether is the object of the preceding verb.

> I can’t decide **whether** to paint the wall green or blue. (or to paint
>   the wall blue)
>
> She didn’t know **whether** he was laughing or crying.

I guess "whether John has heard about ..." is a subordinate clause, but I can't tell what is the main clause. Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is true, whether you like it or not. :) :) Where you say; "I also understand another case", the grammar is inaccurate.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you. "I also understand another case". Did I misuse "another"?

Comment: @Lambie I guess I got it, the "whether ..." part, what does "this" refer to? Does it mean the fact "there is usually only one reason"?

Comment: _Whether_ is a _wh_-word like _what_ and _when_. It introduces an embedded yes/no question: _I don't know whether he's laughing or crying_ means "I don't know the answer to the question 'Is he laughing or crying?'" Since yes/no questions give only two alternatives, often _whether_ can be replaced by _if_.

Comment: No, "this" basically refers to the entire first statement  in the text. It is not that "I also understand another case" is grammatically wrong. It isn't. The grammar is OK, but we'd say something like: I understand there is also another case: x. :)

Answer (score 0):

"This is true" is the main clause, and "whether...." is the subordinate clause.

> ... this is true, whether John has heard about ...

Since this clause follows a to-be verb, "whether" not "if" is used.

In the second example:

> ... this is true, no matter John has heard about ...

"no matter" does not introduce the indirect question of those things John may or may not have heard about.  Introducing a series might utilize "no matter" (without "or not"):

> ... this is true, no matter **what** John has heard about this specific case, this specific trial, or this specific murderer.

Use of "no matter" alone does not establish a connection with "or not" at the end of the sentence. This would need to include "whether" or "if" to make the connection, but "if" would not be an option for an indirect question after a to-be verb in the main clause, and "no matter whether" would be redundant/unnecessary.  Use of "no matter" may be interchangeable with "whether" in some situations, but not here.

Comment: Thank you so much. "Introducing a series might utilize", is "series" a grammar term here?

Comment: No, not a grammar term.  This just happens to occur in this example.  The independent part here is "what John has heard" that happens in this sentence to continue with a series/list of things he may have heard about.  The introductory "no matter what" is a choice that may have been "regardless of what" or something similar.  The point in that example was to show that "no matter" cannot stand alone, it needed "what" to make sense.